# Filter dataframe with vector PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and Stackoverflow.
I want to set a filtered Dataframe into a vector.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'ds': ['2018-11-03', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04'], 
    'y': [117466, 100, 200], 
    'n_item' : [45001,88888, 88888]})
```

I want to filter by item, and allocate into "train vector", because i want later train by item.

I'm trying the following code:

```
for n in items:
    train[n]=df.loc[df["n_item"]==n]
print(train)
```

But i got this error :

```
Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post text format of DataFrame instead of image and what is train variable?

Comment: Hello Epsi, I want to define train and test variables for each item for later use in a Prophet model separated.